# How to fix function execution order

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, node-pdfkit

I'm making a pdf file with pdfkit and sending it as attachment to email with nodemailer but it sends 0 byte output.pdf.

I guess the problem is in function execution order - it start to send email before pdf file is created. I just don't understand how to fix it...

```
app.post("/addressofpost", function(req, res){
  var abc = req.body.entpost;
  var subj = "pdf text"
"use strict"
const doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));
doc.font('PalatinoBold.ttf')
   .fontSize(25)
   .text(subj, 100, 100);
doc.end();

async function main(){
  let account = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp settings",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "mailuser",
      pass: "mailpass"
    }
  });
  let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Sender" <sender@gmail.com',
    to: '"Receiver" <receiver@gmail.com>',
    subject: "Subject",
    text: "email text",
    html: "HTML text"
  };
    let mailOptionsPrint = {
    attachments: [
        {  
              filename: 'output.pdf'
        }],
    from: '"Sergei Dudin" <dudinsergey@mail.ru>',
    to: '"Принтер" <info@moypohod.ru>',
    subject: "Subject",
    text: "email text",
    html: "HTML text"

  };
  let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
  let infoPrint = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptionsPrint)
  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
}
main().catch(console.error);
  console.log(abc);
  res.send('done');
 });
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: app.post is asynchronous, you need to call `main()` from its callback function to wait for it to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You guessed right!

Before we get into fixing the problem, I recommend you to make the `app.post` handler asynchronous so you don't have to create another async function within that handler.

```
app.post("/addressofpost", async (req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

Also, I recommend you not to mix callbacks and async/await when possible. You can create wrapper functions for callback-style async functions, convert them to promises and then `await` on those in your now-async post handler:

```
// I just extracted the pdf creation logic into a function
const createPdf = subj =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const doc = new PDFDocument();
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("output.pdf");

    writeStream.on("finish", () => {
      resolve();
    });

    // TODO: handle errors and reject the promise accordingly

    doc.pipe(writeStream);
    doc
      .font("PalatinoBold.ttf")
      .fontSize(25)
      .text(subj, 100, 100);
    doc.end();
  });
```

with those out of the way you can now do:

```
app.post("/addressofpost", async function(req, res) {
  const abc = req.body.entpost;
  const subj = "pdf text";

  await createPdf(subj);

  let account = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp settings",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "mailuser",
      pass: "mailpass"
    }
  });
  let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Sender" <sender@gmail.com',
    to: '"Receiver" <receiver@gmail.com>',
    subject: "Subject",
    text: "email text",
    html: "HTML text"
  };
  let mailOptionsPrint = {
    attachments: [
      {
        filename: "output.pdf"
      }
    ],
    from: '"Sergei Dudin" <dudinsergey@mail.ru>',
    to: '"Принтер" <info@moypohod.ru>',
    subject: "Subject",
    text: "email text",
    html: "HTML text"
  };
  let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  let infoPrint = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptionsPrint);
  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

  console.log(abc);
  res.send("done");
});
```

Comment: Thank yoг for your time! I put the pdf creating outside the app.post and followed the app.post corrections however it still sends the 0 byte pdf... I guess i need to go deeper to this async thing.